# How to store google search results in python as a json or dict to parse through for specific results?

Tags: python, json, google-search, geopy

I'm querying google for company information with the goal of obtaining the company's address or lat/lon. The ultimate goal is to plot the data in GIS. I realize there are services online that I can pay for that would do this but I want to practice my python skills. I've been going in circles searching the internet for the best way to do this. I've used GeoPy Nominatim in another script but it doesn't work for this dataset (I receive AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude' when searching company name + other descriptions).

I'm able to obtain the information I need with the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

#company name
query = "ADG Creative address"

#print 5 results in case address is not in first result
for i in search(query, advanced=True, sleep_interval=5, num_results=5):
    #j = json.dumps(i)
    print(i)
```

The results look like this:

```
SearchResult(url=https://www.adgcreative.net/, title=ADG Creative | Branding, Design, Content, Video, UX/UI, description=ADG is a creative studio specializing in branding, design, content, video, UX/UI, and complex communications to change behaviors and impact audiences.)
SearchResult(url=https://www.zoominfo.com/c/adg-creative-llc/461999, title=ADG Creative - Overview, News & Competitors, description=ADG Creative's headquarters are located at 7151 Columbia Gateway Dr Ste B, Columbia, Maryland, 21046, United States What is ADG Creative's phone number? ADG ...)
SearchResult(url=https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.adg_creative_llc.4f06c15e0e3edf7fa31353b2ba0736cd.html, title=Adg Creative, LLC Company Profile | Columbia, MD, description=Where is Adg Creative, LLC located? Adg Creative, LLC is located at 7151 Columbia Gateway Dr Ste B Columbia, MD, 21046-2108 United States · What is Adg Creative, ...)
SearchResult(url=https://pitchbook.com/profiles/company/128768-86, title=ADG Creative Company Profile: Acquisition & Investors, description=ADG Creative General Information · 7151 Columbia Gateway Drive · Suite B · Columbia, MD 21046 · United States.)
SearchResult(url=https://www.winmo.com/open/agency/md/columbia/adg-creative/59344, title=ADG Creative - Columbia MD | Agency Profile, Contacts, AOR ..., description=ADG Creative | Agency Profile, Contacts, AOR, Client Relationships. Service: full-service. Main Telephone: (443) 285-0008. Primary Address.)
SearchResult(url=https://www.linkedin.com/company/adg-creative, title=ADG Creative, description=We're a full-stack creative studio, uncomplicating brand and business stories for commercial and public-sector clients for nearly 30 years. Our clients have ...)
```

```
print(type(i))
>> <class 'googlesearch.SearchResult'>
```

Eventually I want to iterate through a list of companies and obtain the address of each.  How do I store the results above to parse through, search for the address, and save the address to a dataframe/file? Open to any other methods using python that may be more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import requests

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual Google Maps Geocoding API key
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Function to retrieve the address, latitude, and longitude for a given company name
def get_company_details(company_name):
    url = f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={company_name}&key={API_KEY}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    if data['status'] == 'OK':
        results = data['results']
        if results:
            address = results[0]['formatted_address']
            latitude = results[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
            longitude = results[0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
            return address, latitude, longitude
    elif data['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
        return 'No address found for the company.', None, None

    return 'Failed to retrieve company details.', None, None

# Main function to read the CSV file, search for company details, and save results in a new file
def search_company_details(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip header row if present

        with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            writer.writerow(['Company', 'Address', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])

            for row in reader:
                company_name = row[0].strip()  # Assuming company name is in the first column
                company_address, latitude, longitude = get_company_details(company_name)
                writer.writerow([company_name, company_address, latitude, longitude])

# Example usage
search_company_details('company_list.csv', 'company_details.csv')
```

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. Please [edit] and explain how you fixed the problem.